# Merging Aqua + Terra MODIS image collections

Tags: modis, google-earth-engine

I run into an error when merging 2 image collections.

Goal: I want to merge the (identical) 250m daily Terra and Aqua MODIS collections into one image collection to obtain one collection with 2 images per day:

```js
// ------MODIS 250M DAILY ----------------------------------------------
var modis_250m_daily_terra =  modis_250m_daily_terra.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end);
var modis_250m_daily_aqua = modis_250m_daily_aqua.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end);`

Method to merge the collections:
>`// ------MERGE MODIS 250M DAILY ----------------------------------------------
var modis1 = modis_250m_daily_terra.merge(modis_250m_daily_aqua);
// sort by date
var modis1 = modis1.sort("system:time_start");
print('MODIS Surface Reflectance Daily 250m',modis1); 
var size_modis1 = modis1.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end).toList(100000).length();
print('Total images in modis1 (250m daily) in current time frame: ', size_modis1);
print('Merged 250m MODIS',modis1);
```

This seems to work until in the following function, this code runs into an error "Invalid argument specified for ee.List(): sur_refl_b01", whereas this function used to work without the merge.

```js
// ------CLOUDFUNCTION----------------------------------------------------
var cloudfunction = function(image){
  //filter the image on its high reflectance part
  var cloud = image.select('sur_refl_b01').rename('cloud');
  var cloud01 = cloud.gt(1000).lt(4000);
  image = image.updateMask(cloud01).addBands(cloud);
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var cloudArea = cloud01.multiply(area).rename('cloudArea');
  image = image.addBands(cloudArea);
  var stats = cloudArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 250,
  });
  return image.set(stats);
};
var collection = modis1.map(cloudfunction);
print ('Clouds pixels', collection);
```

I tried a way to 'join' the collections instead, but this doesn´t give the semidiurnal image collection. Any ideas on how to either avoid the error, or to improve the merge that I applied?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this has anything to do with merge.
You have an error in the [select](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageselect) / [rename](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagerename) part of your `cloudfunction` function that should actually be:

```
var cloud = image.select(['sur_refl_b01'], ['cloud']);
```

Also your `cloud01` declaration looks as it would not work as intended:

```
var cloud01 = cloud.gt(1000).and(cloud.lt(4000));
```

Following OP's comment I think the problem may be solved by surrounding  `merge` in an `ee.ImageCollection` statement:

```
var modis1 = ee.ImageCollection(modis_250m_daily_terra.merge(modis_250m_daily_aqua))
```

As an aside, for efficiency reasons, I would select the `sur_refl_b01` band from `modis1` image collection and map `cloudfunction` on it rather than selecting the band on an image by image basis inside the function itself. Something like this (not tested):

```
var modis1 = ee.ImageCollection(
      modis_250m_daily_terra.merge(modis_250m_daily_aqua))
    .sort("system:time_start");

var modis_clouds = modis1.select(['sur_refl_b01'], ['cloud']);

function cloudfunction(image){
  var cloud01   = image.gt(1000).and(image.lt(4000));
  var area      = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var cloudArea = cloud01.multiply(area).rename('cloudArea');
  var stats = cloudArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 250,
  });
  return image
    .updateMask(cloud01)
    .addBands(cloudArea)
    .set(stats);
}

var collection = modis_clouds.map(cloudfunction);
print ('Clouds pixels', collection);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It partially solves the fact of running into the error that I mentioned, but now it refers to `image.select(...).rename is not a function`. Also, it used to run with the given code if I apply it to 1 dataset, but started bugging when I applied the merge.